# RunTime-Error 424; Trying to DIM a named (found in multiple workbooks) Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a monthly report, so I have a template that I update each month, then run code to update dozens of workbooks. I want to set the specific worksheet that needs sorted, so that I only need to change 1 line of code each month (not dozens).

I have successfully set each of my workbooks as WB1 (the template), WB2, WB3, etc. and each workbook has the same worksheets (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.). My code will copy what I do in the template, paste it into each workbook, update their pivot tables, then sort the results on the monthly sheets.

```
'Dim March worksheet?

Dim WS As Worksheets
    Set WS = Workbook.Sheets("Mar")

'sort for worksheets
'Macro3 Macro


wb2.WS.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C190" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wb2.WS.Sort
        .SetRange Range("B2:E189")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        .SetRange Range("B191:E8040")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

I want to be able to change the dim (i.e. to "APR" for next month), as I have many workbooks that need sorted on that sheet. Currently, if I dont try to Dim the worksheet and just replace WS with Worksheets("Mar") it works, but this will require dozens of changes to "APR", "May", and so on. I want to only change the "Mar" in the line that I set the variable.

Answer (score 1):

`Dim WS As Worksheets` is part of the problem. You want it `As Worksheet` (no "s", it's one sheet, not a collection of sheets). Then you try to assign it:

```
Set WS = Workbook.Sheets("Mar")
```

We don't know what `Workbook` is, but assuming it's holding an valid object reference to the `Workbook` object you mean to work with, you'll want to dereference the sheet from the `Worksheets` collection to avoid surprises later: `Sheets` can contain `Worksheet` objects, but also `Chart` items, and half a dozen other non-worksheet legacy sheet types that don't have a `Range` member.

```
wb2.WS.Sort....
```

Assuming `wb2` already holds a reference to the `Workbook` object you mean to work with (?), it's a `Workbook` object exposing the members of the `Workbook` interface, which doesn't include any `WS` member. If `WS` is the `Worksheet` object declared & assigned above, then you don't need to qualify it: like a `Range` knows what `Worksheet` it belongs to, a `Worksheet` knows what `Workbook` is belongs to.

Did you mean to work with `WS` directly?

```
WS.Sort.....
```

Further down:

```
.SetRange Range("B2:E189")
```

That unqualified `Range` is implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is currently the `ActiveSheet` - probably not what you mean to do. Should that be `WS.Range`?